# Handshake terminated by server: 403 (ACCESS-REFUSED) with message "ACCESS_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, http-status-code-403

I allready have a project with rabbitmq and nodejs, but when a start my worker
`node  myWorker.js`
I get ths error:

```
2023-11-27 15:40:24.359 [info] [env] RabbitMQ Instance: [undefined@undefined]
2023-11-27 15:40:24.360 [info] [env] Third Party's timeout: [3] sec
2023-11-27 15:40:24.362 [info] [env] -->  <--
/DATA/rabbitmq/amqp/worker/consumer.js:21
            throw error0;
            ^

Error: Handshake terminated by server: 403 (ACCESS-REFUSED) with message "ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile."
    at afterStartOk (/DATA/rabbitmq/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:223:12)
    at /DATA/rabbitmq/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:159:12
    at Socket.recv (/DATA/rabbitmq/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:507:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:557:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
```

The steps to create the credentials for rabbit
´´´rabbitmqctl set_user_tags myuser administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
´´´
If I go to the web page I can login with no problem, but when I start the worker, the error appear.

Please, someone help me.

Comment: Can you share the parameters for your connection, specifically the vhost info? Just want to make sure that you provided the correct rights to the correct vhost

Comment: PORT=8080

RMQ_USER=myuser
RMQ_PASSWORD=pwds
RMQ_URL=amqp://MyIPADDRESS:5672

ONEG_TIMEOUT=3

ADMIN_PORT = 8090
All these is in the prod.env
And to configure Rabbit user
systemctl enable --now rabbitmq-server.service
rabbitmqctl status
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
rabbitmqctl add_user rmquser pwds
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags myuser administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"

Comment: Based on the name of your script and the rights provided, I'm assuming your code tries to consume from a queue. Also from your comments, I guess the web page you mention is the rabbitmq admin gui, are those assumptions correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: Ok, so you should be able to confirm in the admin gui that the queue exists and that the vhost it's on is "/". Can you verify those facts?

Comment: Yes, the queue exists and the vhost is /

Comment: would you by any chance try and create/assert the queue and/or other components in your code?

Comment: Sure. I already created that queue and verified it in the rabbit portal.

Comment: Ok, sorry, reached the end of the logic. (last guess I had was that potentially the user didn't have the rights for queue creation while the code tried to do it, but I tested it with write "." pattern, and it seems to work.
Have you checked the logs of the rabbitmq instance?

Comment: [error] <0.26309.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.26309.0> (127.0.0.1:50684 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, state: starting):
[error] <0.26309.0> PLAIN login refused: user '' attempted to log in with a blank password, which is prohibited by the internal authN backend. To use TLS/x509 certificate-based authentication, see the rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl plugin and configure the client to use the EXTERNAL authentication mechanism. Alternatively change the password for the user to be non-blank.

Comment: Well, seems you have an issue in your code populating the password for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The probles was solved creating a variable "prod" for the root user